# Hades, in Greek Mythology, was he really a bad guy, or just a hard to understand God?

Tags: greek, underworld, hades

I'm writing a research paper on Hades, king of the underworld, and I really wanted to know if Hades was really a bad guy.

I have many pages of evidence saying that he isn't. But I would like to know your guys' opinion.

Comment: This sight isn't really used for opinions, but I like to think he was a good guy. He did few things in Myth that were bad, kidnap his wife/niece, had an affair... But, his wife loves him and the affair did end when Persephone found out. A few things on why Hades is a good guy/god: let Orpheus take his wife back as long as he didn't look back (But thinking Hades was a bad guy in a way that made him think she wasn't behind him, looked back. Not Hades fault.), Heracles comes down for his 12th labor asking Hades if could borrow Kerberos (Cerberus in Latin) (he said yes, as long as he took him back

Comment: Also, when two men came down to claim Persephone as one guy's wife, he was justified in punishing them. Heracles came down and freed one, but was stopped from freeing the other because he was the one who was going to claim Persephone. Completely justified in my opinion.

Comment: I read about that and I was happy that he did that, makes him a reliable deity

Comment: Which part? I wrote a lot.

Comment: The Heracles story, he willingly let him take Cerberus, as long as he wasn't harmed. (so Heracles used no weapons to capture him, then returned him to Hades.)

Comment: Yes, that one. He told Heracles could have him, but had to use his bear hands. Another thing I just realized. If Hades says yes to something, there is a catch to make sure the person is deserving of his, for lack of a better word, mercy.

Comment: He usually had them go on a quest to prove that they deserve what they want, and if they fail, he takes their soul.\

Comment: All souls, at death, go to Charon to pay a coin for passage into the Underworld.

Comment: Yep, I recently drew a picture depicting what I think he would have looked like, he's a robed skeleton, (much like the American grim reaper). He has a coin in his mouth and is holding one of those really long sticks to push a boat forward.

Comment: Opinions in chat Id say but chat is kinda dead

Comment: People usually associated 'King of the Dead/Underworld' as 'evil.'  The Ancient Greeks didn't want to talk about him to avoid receiving his attention because they feared death.

Comment: @AndrewJohnson That makes me wonder if we know of any greek temples dedicated to Hades.

Comment: @NuloenTheSeeker The Necromanteion temple is one.

Comment: It's a great question, and one I'd love to address in detail when I have time.  But wanted to confirm that although the Greeks had a strong sense of the binary "good" and "bad", they don't necessarily have the same moral dimension before Plato and Christianity.  So Hades was not evil in the way the Christian ruler of the underworld is, even though the Greek underworld was the major template (see Dante's *Inferno*).  It's not unlikely the relative lack of stories about Hades have to do with a general aversion to death.

Comment: You may also want to look a the Roman variants, including [Diis/Dis Pater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABs_Pater#Mythology), sort of an underworld, anti-Zeus.  Re: "Is Hades a bad guy?"  He abducts and forces his niece into marriage, which is certainly unsavory, but Persephone comes to be more honored, and an entire mystery cult involving rebirth "springs up" around her.  (See: [Eleusinian Mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusinian_Mysteries)).

Comment: @DukeZhou I was thinking more of how is Hades seen in popular culture, today and whatnot. Some people see him as Satan, which in the Christian sense is the worst thing to be. But Hades isn't a bad guy. Pop culture seems to think so, though.

Answer (score 6):

Hades main story involved the abduction of his niece, the Kore (aka Persephone), and subsequent forced marriage.  So, from a modern perspective, we could say he is a bad guy. But, it's important to remember that incest among the gods is not a crime--Zeus married his own sister!  Forced marriage was also the norm, certainly for nobles, until fairly recently.  Hades shared his throne with Persephone, and, through the [Eleusinian Mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusinian_Mysteries), she becomes a goddess most esteemed.

Hades is often regarded as the "anti-Zeus" [see [Diis/Dis Pater]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C4%ABs_Pater)
--Zeus' realm is the sky which is filled with light; Hades realm is eternal darkness.  So it would be easy to see Hades as "evil", except that Zeus is not strictly "good".  (The pagan "Sky Father" is as susceptible to human foibles as anyone, despite his cleverness--Hector has far more dignity than Zeus!)

As Hades transforms into the Roman variant, he is much more associated with the wealth of the subterranean regions--[Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto_(mythology)) ("wealth", from the Greek [πλοῦτος](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dplou%3Dtos1)). In the Orphic Tradition, [Eubuleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eubuleus) ("wise in counselor") is associated with both Hades and Zeus.  [Heraclitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hades#cite_note-56) even suggested that Hades and Dionysus are the same god, representing the life/death dichotomy in the context of eternal renewal.

[Theoi has a nice compendium of Hades references](https://www.theoi.com/Khthonios/Haides.html). My sense is that Hades mostly chilled and did his thing.  In terms of bad behavior, Zeus is sort of the poster boy for that, and Hades is, by comparison, pretty well behaved and low-key.

- Hades is more complex than commonly understood.  He is not bad or evil in the Christian sense, but propitiated in that humans tend to fear death.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to clear up the stereotype that surrounds Hades and makes him look like a bad guy. In modern time whenever you watch a movie or play a videogame where Hades is one of the characters they make it seem as though he is evil and I think that's based around the fact that he rules the underworld. Let's go back in time to how it was he came to be the ruler of the underworld. Hades, Poseidon, and Zeus, the three oldest brothers among the children of their father Cronus came together and killed Cronus to stop his rampage of destruction and eating his children. In this process, it is known for sure that Zeus was the one to perform the final strike that ended Cronus and it was after that when they decided who of the three brothers would either control the sea, the sky, or the underworld. You can read whatever source you would like but you will never find a certain and reliable answer as the how this was decided but we do know the outcome. Zeus became the god of the sky and the ruler of Olympus while Poseidon became the ruler of the sea and Hades was appointed (yes I said appointed) to be the ruler of the underworld. One story says that it was all decided by a coin toss which determined their positions by chance while another story states that because hades was the oldest of the three he was considered the most responsible and was sent to manage the underworld and the third most common story is that they drew lots. Since there are so many variations of the story you simply cannot consider any of them reliable. Regardless of this came to be all the stories do happen to have one thing in common. None of them picked their roles by choice, it was all chance and literally any of them could have ended up as the ruler of the underworld. Another stereotype is that Zeus is a good guy when in reality, he has abused the fact that he is the ruler of Olympus to get away with raping several other goddesses including his own sister Hera and even his brothers wife. Sure you might make the argument that Hades kidnapped his wife before marrying her but he never raped her. Instead he tried to overwhelm her with luxuries and even then he didn't keep her there for too long against her will. He did let her go but she came back. Now you might want to argue that Persephone was Hades niece and that's just as wrong as Zeus marrying his sister Hera. Zeus raped Hera but Hades did not rape Persephone and believe it or not, marrying people related to you was a very common thing among gods in almost every religion as well as humans all throughout history. On top of this Persephone is one of Zeus's many daughters and Zeus disguised himself as hades just to sleep with her and they even had a child. I would go on with all the nasty things that Zeus has done but this article is supposed to be about Hades.

Answer (score 0):

Know that the only noteworthy "evil" thing he did is kidnap kore/Persephone and marry her, and even then, she loved him just as he loved her. He is one of the only gods to only marry out of love. The idea of him being evil is a Christianized view of him because of his association with death. Though he was more the guardian god of the dead than the actual god of death, who was Thanatos.