# Satan and Angra Mainyu

Tags: christianity, underworld, bible, the-devil, demons

Many people say that Satan(Lucifer's Devil side) completely originated from Ahriman. I don't know much about the Avesta of Zoroaster but is that true?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who was the first Satan like deity/creature/person in mythology?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/5420/who-was-the-first-satan-like-deity-creature-person-in-mythology)

Answer (score 1):

> Satan (or the devil) obtained for Jewish ideas almost the same
>   significance as Ahriman for Persian. Indeed, in certain respects he
>   developed greater power than his Persian counterpart, inasmuch as he
>   succeeded in corrupting the immediate followers of God, whereas
>   Ahriman, in his contest with Ahuramazda, did not achieve such success.
>   The Jews tried to preserve the monism that was their original view by
>   explaining the rise of dualism as due to a fall among the originally
>   good spirits.

From [AHRIMAN (Angro-mainyush; identical with Satan, the Devil, Armilus)](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/1003-ahriman)